# How to show 'Save as' dialog box using PHP for text files

Tags: php, http, mime-types

How can I show the 'Save as' dialog box using PHP which will ask the user to download a string as a text file? Basically I will retrieve some values from the database, and want then to be able to download a .txt file which contains this data.

Comment: just throwing this in here because I needed it in addition to emil's answer.... for line breaks: echo "\r\n";

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This should work:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.txt"');
```

Answer (score 6):

Just to expand on @Emil H's answer:

Using those header calls will only work in the context of a new request. You'll need to implement something that allows your script to know when it's actually sending the file as  opposed to when it's displaying a form telling the user to download the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?
header ("Content-Type: application/download");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$yourfile");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize("$yourfile"));
$fp = fopen("$yourfile", "r");
fpassthru($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the usage of **header()**:

[Official PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/header):

> **header()** is used to send a raw HTTP  header. See the » HTTP/1.1 specification  for more information on HTTP headers.
>
> Remember that **header()** must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with **include()**, or **require()**, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before **header()** is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

So basically, you're changing the entire page when you're using header(). Make sure the only contents you echo are the string.