# Check size of external files, php

Tags: php, html, external, filesize

I get files by their urls by this code

```
file_get_contents($_POST['url'];
```

Then I do something with them.

But I don't want to operate with big files, how do I limit size of received file?

It should throw an error if file is bigger than 500kb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440270/serving-file-hosted-on-another-server-as-download/5440303#5440303) to this question. You need to have the cURL extension, with which you can make a `HEAD` HTTP request to the remote server. The response will let you know how big the file is, and you can then decide accordingly.

You are interested specifically in this line:

```
$size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);
```

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url), $url = post['url']?

Comment: @Rooney: Yes, that's a placeholder for the url you are interested in.

Answer (score 5):

Agree with @Jon

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //specify the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
    $head = curl_exec($ch);

    $size = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

    if(<limit the $size>){
    file_get_contents($url);
    }
```