# filesize() function does not work

Tags: php, file, size

I uploaded some files to a folder, and when I use filesize function I get this message:

```
Message: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for http://www.books.tahasoft.com/216.ppt
```

the path of file is:

```
http://www.books.tahasoft.com/216.ppt
```

and here is my code:

```
<?
echo filesize("http://www.books.tahasoft.com/216.ppt");
?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you open the file manually?

Comment: filesize (and by extension, stat) isn't reliable when used on URLs. if that code is running on the same server as the url is pointing to, then use the local path, e.g. `filesize('/path/to/file/on/the/server/216.ppt')`.

Comment: @MarcB: Actually, it's documented to not work.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot get the filesize over the http protocol.

If the file is on the local server, use filesize with a absolute or a relative path in the filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this.......

```
 $ch = curl_init('http://www.books.tahasoft.com/216.ppt');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 $size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

 curl_close($ch);
 echo $size;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `http://` stream wrapper [does not support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) the `stat` family of functions, so you can't do this with `filesize` as the documentation warns:

> As of PHP 5.0.0, this function can also be used with *some* URL
>   wrappers. Refer to Supported Protocols and Wrappers to determine which
>   wrappers support stat() family of functionality.

If you need the filesize over HTTP without having to download the whole file first, you might be able to get it using `curl`; you can see how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440270/serving-file-hosted-on-another-server-as-download/5440303#5440303). But keep in mind that this is dependent on what headers the remote server decides to send back; there is *no guarantee* that it will always work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this instead.

```
echo strlen(file_get_contents("http://www.books.tahasoft.com/216.ppt"));
```

Comment: wow, downloading a possible very huge file, just to get the filesize? (I did not downvote)

Comment: -1 because `file_get_contents` over the network to get the filesize?

Comment: @Jon But if you want to get the size, you need to download it for guarantee, right?

Comment: @xdazz: If I want to see if a store is open I need to go over there for a guarantee -- but I can sure *try* calling them first. Also, IMHO it is not very nice to offer such a solution to a newbie without mentioning any alternatives and/or the (huge!) drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do, to perform a HTTP [HEAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request to the file, and check existence of the `Content-Length` header; the only other way would be to *download* the whole file, and check its length - but in my opinion is not a real option.

Answer (score 0):

for getting the size of your file from filesize() function, you need to add folder path of the file to get the size.

==> False Method: $filePath = "http://www.books.tahasoft.com/216.ppt";

==> True Method: folder path like: $filePath = '/home/www/uploadpath/filename';

So, you get the result by calling the function like:

filesize($filePath);

OR

If you want to get the size from the link, you have to do like this:

strlen(file_get_contents("http://www.books.tahasoft.com/216.ppt"));