# How does the download function work

Tags: php

I have a webpage where I have links to the photographs and information regarding this being stored in MySQL.  Now if I want to add a download button for images/audio, how do I do that, using PHP?

Comment: i have no idea. any bit of the solution will work. any link to the solution.

Comment: clue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968106/generate-download-file-link-in-php

Comment: You really haven't provided enough information to provide an answer, short of writing your application for you. You'll need a button, or some other HTML element that resembles a button, that links to some action in your PHP script. You're going to need to show more information if you expect a useful answer. We're here to help you solve _problems_, not to do your work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming each file has an ID in the database as well, simply have your download button link to a php page which is setup like this:

```
<?php 

//$file = fetch file data from db based off of $_GET['id']

header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); 

readfile($file);
```