# Change PHP Generated File Link Into Downloadable Click

Tags: php, file, download

I have been looking for a solution to a problem I'm having with my code. The nearest solution to my problem was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968106/generate-download-file-link-in-php#answer-1968116) however that solution didn't fit my problem.

I'm listing uploaded files in PHP on my page, with each file being an  to the file's location. That works fine, however I am new to PHP and am having difficulty in implementing others code.

Here's the code I'm using, if it helps:

```
<?php
    // Directory Location
    $directory = './';

    // Timezone (UK BST)
    date_default_timezone_set(WET);

    // Define Byte Sizes
    function file_size($size)
    {
        $filesizename = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB");
        return $size ? round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 1) . $filesizename[$i] : '0 Bytes';
    }

    // fetches all executable files in that directory and loop over each
    foreach(glob($file.'*wav') as $file) {

        // List Link to Files & Date/Time
        echo '<a class="files" href="'.$file.'">
              <span class="time">' . date("m/d/Y H:i", filemtime($file));

        // List File Name & Size
        echo '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; '.$file.'&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        Size: '.file_size(filesize($file)).'</a>';
    }
?>
```

If possible I would prefer the download links to be generated in PHP for each individual file. The files are listed like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8Lxa.png

Comment: The reference you used of SO answer is a correct way to do. It should  also work for you.

Comment: @NullVoid I can't get it to work, I'm not good enough with PHP yet to fit that code into mine.

Comment: See the answer of @luk2302. He has suggested correct way to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the code of the mentioned SO answer in the following way:
change the link you display to the following which direct the user to download.php and hands over the information which file to download:

```
echo '<a class="files" href="download.php?file='.$file.'"> ...
```

Then add an download.php with the content of the SO answer but using

```
$filename = $_GET['file'];
```

to get the given filename out of the url.

Additionally you have to change `header('Content-Type: application/pdf');` to whatever filetype you want to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

for list of files list.php e.g.

```
<?php

// salt for md5 check
$saltmd5 = '76t7gjbertdfv56w45sdve54etyv';


// Directory Location
$directory = './';

// Timezone (UK BST)
date_default_timezone_set(WET);

// Define Byte Sizes
function file_size($size)
{
    $filesizename = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB");
    return $size ? round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 1) . $filesizename[$i] : '0 Bytes';
}

// fetches all executable files in that directory and loop over each
foreach(glob($file.'*wav') as $file) {

    // List Link to Files & Date/Time
    $file_md5 = md5("$file$saltmd5"); // md5 file check
    $file_link = "dwn.php?f=$file&c=$file_md5"; // file link

    echo '<a class="files" href="'.$file_link.'">
          <span class="time">' . date("m/d/Y H:i", filemtime($file));

    // List File Name & Size
    echo '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; '.$file.'&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    Size: '.file_size(filesize($file)).'</a>';
}


?>
```

for download of files dwn.php e.g.

```
    <?php

    // salt for md5 check
    $saltmd5 = '76t7gjbertdfv56w45sdve54etyv';

$file_md5 = $_GET['c']; // md5 file check
$filename = $_GET['f']; // the name of the file that is downloaded


if($file_md5==md5("$filename$saltmd5")){

     // Directory Location
    $directory = './';

$size = filesize($directory . $filename) ;
header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"". $filename ."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ". $size ."");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $filename ."\"");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
echo (readfile($directory . $filename));


}
else
   {
    die('no existo'); //bad file
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer was also very useful to my question.