# SaveFile dialog in MVC razor on link click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to ask, how can I open savefile dialog in mvc razor4?
I wanted use normal savefile dialog but I have found out that it can be used only in Win forms. So I search in google but didn't find good solution. Only that there is

```
<input type="file" />
```

but I think it is problematic to overwrite his look.

I have something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ExcelExport","Home")"><img src="@Url.Content("~/images/excel_icon.png")" id="excel-export-img" /></a>
```

I want to display Savefile dialog after click to that.
Know anyone about some materials about it or how to do it?

Thak you.

Comment: What does that action (`"ExcelExport"`) return?  If it returns a `File()` then there should indeed be a Save File dialog, unless of course the browser is configured not to display it.  You can't really display the dialog directly in a web application.  What you can do is send a file to the client, and let the client decide what to do with it.

Comment: _"I want to display Savefile dialog after click to that"_. That is not up to you. The browser decides what to do with a file download. See [How to show 'Save as' dialog box using PHP for text files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732063/how-to-show-save-as-dialog-box-using-php-for-text-files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that HTTP doesn't necessarily have a concept of "files."  It has requests and responses.  And each of those has headers and content.  So what you want is to return the contents of a file with a header indicating that it is a "file" and should be treated as such.  It's still up to the browser how to actually handle it, of course.

The way to do this in ASP.NET MVC is to [return a `File()` from your controller action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file.aspx).  Something like this:

```
return File("SomeFile.xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
```

There are, of course, several overloads for the `File()` method, some of which accept a byte array or stream instead of the name of an actual server-side file.

Comment: Thank you, work perfectly. Next thing I didn't know is that browser will do it for me.